# Aggregating two tables into time series

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, time-series, window-functions

Lets say I have two tables that hold data oriented in time in pairs (date, data). One of them holds my daily expenses and the other my daily income. The date means when does this expense/income rate start.

For example: if I have two records in the income table: (2020-01-01, 50), (2020-02-14, 100) that means that between 2020-01-01 and 2020-02-14 my incomes were 50 units a day and after 2020-02-14 the income was 100 units a day. The same goes with the expenses.

I would like to generate a time series for a given interval in a postgres table (probably with time generate_series(date,date,interval) function) of which one row would look like this:
(day, income, expense)

For example if I had the income table looking like this:

```
+------------+--------+
|    date    | income |
+------------+--------+
| 2020-02-12 |     50 |
| 2020-02-14 |    100 |
+------------+--------+
```

and the expense like this:

```
+------------+--------------+
|    date    | expenses     |
+------------+--------------+
| 2020-02-12 |           70 |
| 2020-02-13 |           50 |
+------------+--------------+
```

I would like the outcome for the interval from 2020-02-12 to 2020-02-15 to look like this:

```
+------------+--------+--------------+
|    day     | income | expenses     |
+------------+--------+--------------+
| 2020-02-12 |     50 |           70 |
| 2020-02-13 |     50 |           50 |
| 2020-02-14 |    100 |           50 |
| 2020-02-15 |    100 |           50 |
+------------+--------+--------------+
```

So that later I could for example calculate my profits, losses and other stats. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Do you know that the dates are unique?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky. You can `full join` on the date, but then you need to fill the gaps. Postgres does not support `ignore nulls` on window functions, so one option is to use a conditional sum to build groups, and then `first_value()`:

```
select
    date,
    first_value(income)  over(partition by grp_i order by date) income,
    first_value(expense) over(partition by grp_e order by date) expense
from (
    select
        date, 
        i.income,
        e.expense,
        count(*) filter(where i.income  is not null) over(order by date) grp_i,
        count(*) filter(where e.expense is not null) over(order by date) grp_e
    from incomes i
    full join expenses e using(date)
) t
```

On the other hand, you can also start from a chosen date period (using `generate_series()`), and then bring the tables with `left join`s. The rest of the logic is unchanged:

```
select
    date,
    first_value(income)  over(partition by grp_i order by date) income,
    first_value(expense) over(partition by grp_e order by date) expense
from (
    select
        d.date, 
        i.income,
        e.expense,
        count(*) filter(where i.income  is not null) over(order by d.date) grp_i,
        count(*) filter(where e.expense is not null) over(order by d.date) grp_e
    from generate_series(date '2020-02-12', date '2020-02-15', interval '1' day) d(date)
    left join incomes  i on i.date = d.date
    left join expenses e on e.date = d.date
) t
order by date
```

Answer (score 0):

One method -- if your data is not too big -- is a lateral join:

```
select gs.dte, i.income, e.expense
from generate_series('2020-02-12'::date, '2020-02-15'::date, interval '1 day'
                   ) gs(dte) left join lateral
     (select i.*
      from income i
      where i.date <= gs.dte
      order by i.date desc
      limit 1
     ) i
     on true left join lateral
     (select e.*
      from expense e
      where e.date <= gs.dte
      order by e.date desc
      limit 1
     ) e
     on true;
```

Another option is to use `generate_series()` on each table independently to calculate the values.  Both start on the earliest date, so this works:

```
select i.date, i.income, e.expense
from (select gs.date, i.income
      from (select i.*, lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
            from income i
           ) i cross join lateral
           generate_series(date, coalesce(next_date - interval '1 day', '2020-02-15'::date), interval '1 day') gs(date)
     ) i join
     (select gs.date, e.expense
      from (select e.*, lead(date) over (order by date) as next_date
            from expense e
           ) e cross join lateral
           generate_series(date, coalesce(e.next_date - interval '1 day', '2020-02-15'::date), interval '1 day') gs(date)
     ) e 
     on i.date = e.date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b16d65424cdf0e0b432aee2e54900024) is a db<>fiddle of both solutions.

This is easily modified to handle the situation where the two series do not start on the same date.